# How do I update an SQLite database value in an AlarmManager in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, alarmmanager

I have code that runs perfectly fine on a button click but I now need to run it in Alarm Service automatically. When I call the method ( `updateDays()` ) to be executed in a `**Runnable**` interface, It doesn't get called at all. The database does not get updated as expected. Am I really doing it right?

```
DbAdapter  mDbHelper;

Cursor mCursor;

Runnable mUpdateTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      long maxWaitTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10*1000;
      while (System.currentTimeMillis() < maxWaitTime) {
        synchronized (mBinder) {
          try {
             updateDays();
             mBinder.wait(maxWaitTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
          } catch (Exception e) {

          }
       }
   }
}



private void updateDays() {
    mDbHelper.open();
    if(mCursor != null) {
      mDbHelper.updateDL (DbAdapter.KEY_ID,
               mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapter.KEY_DAYS))-1,
               DbAdapter.KEY_DATE_TIME);
      mDbHelper.close();

Toast.makeText(this, "Update done !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

**EDIT**

**`onReceive`** method in my broadcast receiver

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
int rowid = intent.getExtras().getInt(DbAdapter.KEY_ID);

        Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
        i.putExtra(DbAdapter.KEY_ID, rowid);
        context.startService(i);
        }
```

**EDIT 2**

My Service `**onCreate**` method

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
mNofitication = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

displayNotification();

Thread tr = new Thread(null, mUpdateTask, "AlarmService");
tr.start();
}
```

Comment: Follow these instructions to examine your Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this If you cannot interpret that stack trace, edit your question to provide it.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks for downvoting but it looks like you have not got me right. I said it in the explanation above the code that I get the null pointer exception.

Comment: First, I did not downvote you. Second, out of ~7 billion people on the planet, you are the only one who might know *where* you are getting a `NullPointerException`. This is why I suggested that if you cannot interpret that stack trace, edit your question to provide it. To be able to help you, *we* need to know *where* in your code you are triggering a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @Dadani: The question isn't bad, its just that u havent provided enough info for some one to suggest an answer. Upvote for the question.

Comment: @CommonsWare, sorry, I thought of it as you who downvoted coz you were the only one I saw commented and I had no way to know who downvoted. Thanks for your suggestions. I have added more info for clarity.

Comment: post the content of your intent service. (the `onCreate` part in particular if you have one)

Comment: @Zax, thanks. More info now provided.

Comment: Question edited, please check back to help.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I can see that you can get a `NullPointerException` on line 116 of [`IntentService.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java) would be if your service overrides `onCreate()` and does not chain to the superclass.

Comment: I have added the onCreate method with its content, check it out and see whether it is the one causing the problem.

Comment: @Dadani: As I noted in my answer, you are not chaining to the superclass. Call `super.onCreate()` as the first thing that you do in your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: let me give it a try and get back to you shortly

Comment: Thank you for that, it has worked. However that answers only the first part of the question about `NullPointerException`. The database still doesn't get updated. The method `updateDays()` doesn't get called at all.

Answer (score 0):

From your requirement i feel you need to use a pending intent along with the Alarm manager. A sample of the same is shown below:

```
//Creating a PendingIntent
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
MainActivity.this, UNIQUE_ID_RANDOM, intent, 0);
//Creating an AlarmManager and setting the pendingIntent to him
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
+ (5 * 1000), pendingIntent);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Alarm set in " + 5 + " seconds",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Now inside the service you start after say 5 seconds, you can put your above code and give a try. Below is the sample:

```
public class MyService extends Service{

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    //Your database opening code should come here. But take care of the syntax related constructs.
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
 }


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

I hope this helps you.

Regards,

Zax

Comment: thanks but I am using alarm manager instead of simple service that is subject to GC by the OS. Time is critical in my case here.